# AADSTS90008: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

Tags: azure, oauth, multi-tenant

I am trying to login external tenant here. I have added below permissions to my app.

[image]

But i am getting below error. but i have gave that permission already.

```
AADSTS90008: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '268a9999-0000-4e61-99f5-020000f777b2'(test.app.test). This happened because application is misconfigured: it must require access to Microsoft Graph by specifying at least 'Sign in and read user profile' permission.\r\nTrace ID: bf014111-2e3f-4c11-1115e-de2fb6951800\r\nCorrelation ID: e0003455-0000-0000-ae4c-2264f23f5747\r\nTimestamp: 2021-12-10 09:24:34Z
```

my azure AzureAD version is v1

Comment: May i know whether you gave the user.read.all permission or not . If not please try to give the permission and then save and refresh then try again.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT yes i gave. you can see it my question image

Comment: Thanks. Could you please refer this https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-aadsts90008-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application/

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose i will try thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few of the workarounds to solve the above issue:

- If you have given all the permission You’ll need to make sure, that you’ve granted the **Microsoft graph access to your application data**  (which you can do yourself, if the Azure Active Directory’s settings allow that and the application only wants delegated permissions without admin-consent) or to all users (which requires an administrator to grant the permissions).

[image]

- If your application is on another tenant, then giving admin consent to the Microsoft Graph from your tenant can be done as Suggested by @amanpreetsingh-msft  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/543582/is-there-a-way-to-grant-admin-consent-to-a-multi-t.html) .

> Admin Consent via Azure Portal can only be provided for the tenant
> where the application is registered in the first place. Users or
> Administrators of other tenants cannot consent via Azure Portal and it
> has to be done,
>
> 1. Either when user/administrator accesses the multi-tenant application first time.
> 2. Or by constructing the Admin Consent URL and sharing it with the Administrators of the other tenants.
>
> Below is an example of the Admin Consent URL:
>
> 1. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent`
> 2. `?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e`
> 3. `&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send`
> 4. `&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions`
> 5. `&state=12345`

For more information please refer the below links:

- MS Q&A: [AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/545439/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-cons.html) .
- BLOG - [Fixed – AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID](https://nishantrana.me/2020/12/01/fixed-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application-with-id/)